# Astro server endpoints with nodejs adapter has empty header

Tags: node.js, server-side-rendering, astrojs

I am following this tutorial: [Astro with Firebase][1]https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/backend/google-firebase/
and everything works as expected after I run `npm run dev`. However when I run `npm run build` and start the server with  `node ./dist/server/entry.mjs` I am not able to access headers from the request sent to server.
Here is the server endpoint code:

```
export const get: APIRoute = async ({ request, cookies, redirect }) => {
  /* Get token from header*/
  const idToken = request.headers.get("Authorization")?.split("Bearer ")[1];
  if (!idToken) //idToken null
{
    return new Response(
      "No token found",
      { status: 401 }
    );
  }
 ...
  return redirect("/dashboard");
};
```

I am running newest version of Astro with SSR nodejs (hybrid rendering.

**So far I tried:**

1. Use axios instead of request for HTTP get request
2. Different version of node (18 /20)
3. Add token as a param after my base url (localhost:3000/api/auth?token) - it seems that only plain URL is available on the server side.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution after reading the documentation of Astro more thoroughly. The **hybrid rendering** set in my `astro.config.mjs` by default renders everything as static content even the server endpoints, which was not clear to me from the documentation. So basically configuring output: 'hybrid' we have to tell Astro which routes should be SSR, even the server endpoints. More information here: [Astro - Opting out of pre-rendering](https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/server-side-rendering/#opting-out-of-pre-rendering)

So in my case the solution was to add this line to my server endpoints and everything works great:

```
export const prerender = false; //ADDED LINE
export const get: APIRoute = async ({ request, cookies, redirect }) => {
...
```